# Spring @DataJpaTest with JUnit 5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa, junit5

There doesn't seem to be a specific standard way I can find online that makes `@DataJpaTest` to run correctly.

Is it true that `@DataJpaTest` is not being used nowadays and all tests are run at the service or controller level using `@SpringBootTest`?

```java
    @Repository
    public interface MyBeanRepository extends JpaRepository<MyBean, Long> { 
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.app.repository.*")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.repository.*" })
    public class ConfigurationRepository { 
    }


    @Entity
    public class MyBean {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Version
        @Column(name = "version")
        private Integer version;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 2)
        private String name;
    }

    @DataJpaTest
    public class MyBeanIntegrationTest {

        @Autowired
        MyBeanRepository myBeanRepository;

        @Test
        public void testMarkerMethod() {
        }

        @Test
        public void testCount() {
            Assertions.assertNotNull(myBeanRepository , "Data on demand for 'MyBean' failed to initialize correctly");
        }
    }
```

Running using the Eclipse->Run Junit shows these logs.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
```

Running using gradle test shows the error that init failed.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Test failed.
    Failed tests:
        Test com.app.repository.MyBeanIntegrationTest#initializationError (Task: :test)
```

Here is the gradle script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'

}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    runtimeOnly 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb'
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        // exlcuding junit 4
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }

    /**
        Test Dependencies Follows
    **/


    // junit 5 api
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0"
    // For junit5 parameterised test support
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0"
    // junit 5 implementation
    testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0"
    // Only required to run junit5 test from IDE
    testRuntime "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher"

}
```

**EDIT:**

This has been solved and committed at the same repository.
https://github.com/john77eipe/spring-demo-1-test

Comment: If you respect the standard package layout (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class), everything should work fine.

Comment: code is here to try: https://github.com/john77eipe/spring-demo-1-test

Comment: @JBNizet I couldn't find what went wrong.

Comment: You don't have any main Application class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in the com.app package.

Comment: repository project wouldn't contain the `@SpringBootApplication`  right? Or should we put one there just for this. Also what if this is not a spring boot project instead a spring project, is there a way to make it work just for tests?

Comment: If you put your repositories in a separate project, then as the error indicates, you need to use ContextConfiguration to specify which configuration class you want to load. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

Comment: So I should be annotating like `@ContextConfiguration(classes= {ConfigurationRepository.class})` on the Test class? 
I tried but I get error. No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.repository.MyBeanRepository'

Comment: I updated my answer after checking your repo.

Comment: I have solved it without using `@SpringBootApplicaiton` see my Edit

Answer (score -3):

It was a good idea to add a Github link. I can see following issues there:

1) If you can't have a main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, you can use:

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.repository")
public class MySampleApplication {
}
```

2) Change annotations over your `ConfigurationRepository` class to:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.app.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.repository" })
public class ConfigurationRepository {
```

That should let us proceed to the next point:

3) Your `MyBeanIntegrationTest` should be annotated as:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyAppApplication.class)
public class MyBeanIntegrationTest {
```

4) In `application.yml` you have a small issue with indentation in the last line. Convert tab so spaces and it should be fine.

5) Next thing is `MyBeanRepository` interface. You can't use a method named `findOne` there. Thing is, that in interfaces marked as `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` and so on, methods names need to follow certain rules. If you mark that it will be a repository containing type `MyBean` your method name should be changed to `findById`, because Spring will look for a property named `id` in your bean. Naming it by `findOne` will cause test to fail with:

```
No property findOne found for type MyBean!
```

After fixing these things, your tests pass on my env.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` does runs with an embedded database right?

Comment: RunWith is for JUnit 4. And DataJpaTest is meta-annotated with ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class).

Comment: mate00 I shouldn't be using `@SpringBootApplication` I think I should be using `@ ContextConfiguration` any idea how?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you're can't user `@SpringBootApplication`. Maybe that's why I was downvoted so many times :(

Comment: I updated answer with different annotations than `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @John  use this annotations "@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)"